# How to NSLog JSON before it sends

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, afnetworking

This is my POST request for uploading a file. How can I NSLog the JSON I'm sending to the server before the actual send?

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[dict setObject:twitid forKey:@"twit"];
[dict setObject:hash forKey:@"hash"];

AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];
if ([mediaFile isKindOfClass:[UIImage class]])
{
   imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(mediaFile, 0.5); 
}

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:nil parameters:dict constructingBodyWithBlock: ^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData) {

if ([mediaFile isKindOfClass:[UIImage class]])
        {
          [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"media" fileName:@"picture.png" mimeType:@"image/png"];  
        }
    else if(isThisAudio)
    {
       [formData appendPartWithFileData:mediaFile name:@"media" fileName:@"audio.caf" mimeType:@"audio/caf"];  
    }
    else
    {
        [formData appendPartWithFileData:mediaFile name:@"media" fileName:@"movie.mov" mimeType:@"video/quicktime"];  
    }

}];

AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request

success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON)
{
    NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = JSON;       
    NSLog(@"jsonDictionary: %@",jsonDictionary);
}
failure:^(NSURLRequest *request , NSURLResponse *response , NSError *error , id JSON)
{
    NSLog(@"Failed: %@",[error localizedDescription]);
}];
[operation setUploadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesWritten, long long totalBytesWritten, long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {

    percentDone = ((float)((int)totalBytesWritten) / (float)((int)totalBytesExpectedToWrite)); 
    NSLog(@"Uploaded %f",percentDone);
}];
[httpClient enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:operation];
```

Comment: i cant see any code line where do you append any JSON Data to the Request

Comment: I'm sending a file and a dictionary called dict. I want to print out the all thing before sending it.

Comment: maybe im blind, but i cant find the line of code where you add the "JSON dict"

Comment: Note that you don't send JSON to the server. You send a multi-part form request containing 3 files. It may be that you *receive* JSON.

Answer (score 0):

A good option is to use something like the [Charles proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com) to monitor what is actually being sent over the network. In this way you see what actually happens on the network rather than the state at some point in the code flow.

Comment: Can't i just print it out in the console?

Comment: Not using the Charles proxy approach, no. To print at the console you need to add an NSLog at some point in the code where the data has been generated.

Answer (score 0):

checkout the [NSURLRequest-cURL](https://github.com/andrewroycarter/NSURLRequest-cURL) category.

with the category you can simply:

```
NSLog(@"%s %@", __FUNCTION__, [request cURLCommand])
```